# Can different threads reuse the same marshalled ActiveX interface?

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, com, activex, marshalling

when I marshal ActiveX interface through *Global Interface Table* (GIT), do I need to call `GetInterfaceFromGlobal()` from **every** thread that will use this interface? Alternatively, once one thread gets a pointer to the marshaled interface, that same pointer is good to use from other threads too?

Comment: It is hard to guess how much state is associated with the proxy interface pointer when a thread has a call in progress.  You *might* get away with it if you can ensure yourself that these threads don't use the proxy at the same time.  So you'll have to write *more* code to make this micro-optimization.  Which can't be what you had in mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call it from every thread. Each thread gets its own proxy.

In theory you can use one proxy... it may work. But `GetInterfaceFromGlobal` may also directly return the pure interface if you call it from the creating thread... no proxy needed in this case.

Comment: My experience has been that not all threads needed their proper marshaled interface, reusing the one from the thread that got it first worked fine. However, xMRi is still right that the formal way is to marshal interface to all threads independenly, otherwise we enter a gray zone and things could go wrong without good knowledge why.

Comment: Also if executed from one thread GetInterfaceFromGlobal shares the proxy...